# Computing wiring current, temperature & cross sections

Tags: wiring

How do you compute that when say 115A of current passes through an AWG 3. The temperature is 90 degree Celsius? At what ambient temperature is this computed, and air movement quality?

In the Ampacity and insulation table for example https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/, an AWG 3 has 115A rating for 90C THHN wire.

Answer (score 2):

Usually Standard air temperature and pressure ie 20 deg C and 1 bar, and assumed that it is a single cable, not surrounded by other cables or insulation or "hidden" in a wall, so that heat can be removed by air convection.

But this is always specified by the relevant electrical standards for the country you are working in, so you need to check.

Comment: I was asking about NEC. How did they compute it?

Comment: They most likely calculate the effects using all the heat transfer calculations including conduction, convection and radiation to produce the tables they give, which include their own safety margins and assumptions, but that is very in-depth and if you check the standards then you will probably find they will show the method used in some appendix - at least I found that sort of thing specified when I last looked...